# Precompiled Header within C++ Project in VisualStudio not Linking correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

## Scenario

If have the following directory structure within my VS Project.

```
    project/
      |
      |-- include/
      |     |
      |     pch.h
      |
      |-- src/
      |     |
      |     pch.cpp
      |
      Project.cpp
```

And my files read like this:

> Project.cpp

```cpp
#include "include/pch.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

> pch.h

```cpp
#ifndef _PCH_H
#define _PCH_H

// IO Libraries
#include <iostream>     
#include <iomanip>      
#include <io.h>         
#include <ostream>
#include <conio.h>

... more headers

#endif // !_PCH_H
```

> pch.cpp

```cpp
#include "../include/pch.h"
```

Now, the properties for each element are configured for **Precompiled Headers** as follows:

> Project

```
Precompiled Header                   Use(/Yu)
Precompiled Header File              pch.h
Precompiled Header Output File       $(IntDir)$(TargetName).pch
```

> pch.cpp

```
Precompiled Header                   Create(/Yc)
Precompiled Header File              pch.h
Precompiled Header Output File       $(IntDir)$(TargetName).pch
```

## Problem

When I attempt to compile this project, I receive the following error:

```
Severity    Code     Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error       C2857    '#include' statement specified with the /Ycpch.h command-line option was not found in the source file  

Project File                                           Line  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Workspace\VisualStudio\C++\Poker\Poker\src\pch.cpp  2
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Compiler Error C2857](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2857?view=vs-2019)

> When you use the /Ycfilename option on a source file to create a
>   precompiled header (PCH) file, that source file must include the
>   filename header file. Every file included by the source file, up to
>   and including the specified filename, is included in the PCH file. In
>   other source files compiled by using the /Yufilename option to use the
>   PCH file, an include of filename must be the first non-comment line in
>   the file. The compiler ignores anything in the source file before this
>   include.

Get any of those details wrong and you'll be slapped with a compile error.  Looks to me like the source file you selected for /Yc does not in fact #include "pch.h".